# SSIS Custom Component IDTSVariabeDispenser100 conversion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis

I am trying to create a custom component for SSIS. I am trying to open the expressionBuilder form and for this I need to convert the variable dispenser of the component from the type IDTSVariableDispenser100 to the wrapper type VariableDispenser. I found all i wanted for the other way conversion in the doc :
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtsconvert.aspx.

All, except the only one which is the one I want to use.

Here is a sample of my code for the expressionBuilder :

```
using (var expressionBuilder = ExpressionBuilder.Instantiate(DtsConvert.GetWrapper(vars),
                           variableDispenser,
                           Type.GetType("System.String"),
                           value.ToString()))¸
```

Thank you !!